# Reading from JSON

Tags: json, typescript, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm trying to read my i18n-strings from a JSON file following [this guide](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/typescript.html#type-safe-resources-in-createi18n).

I have `en-US.json`:

```
{
  "world": "the world!"
}
```

And for setting up my Vue app I use:

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import enUS from '../src/i18n/en-US.json'

// Type-define 'en-US' as the master schema for the resource
type MessageSchema = typeof enUS

const i18n = createI18n<[MessageSchema], 'en-US'>({
  locale: 'en-US',
  messages: {
    'en-US': enUS
  }
})
```

This works. But as soon as I add one non-ASCII char (e.g. `"world": "the w@rld!"`), I get the following error message:

```
[plugin:vite-plugin-vue-i18n] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
/home/bernhard/wd/quasar2-project/src/i18n/en-US.json
```

Strangely, this works when I do the following straight in my .ts file:

```
const enUS = {
   "world": "the w@rld!"
}
```

so maybe something wrong with the way the JSON is processed?

Comment: @ _is_ an ASCII char. But it's also a [special character](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#special-characters) for that library.

Comment: strange, always worked... currently upgrading from vue2 to vue3. Do you want to post an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer has two layers.

1. As @jonrsharpe pointed out, there is a [set of special characters](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html#special-characters): `{ } @ $ |` - i.e. for inserting variables. A `@` should i.e. be replaced by `{'@'}`.
2. A bug in how vite processes external json as described [on this bug on Github](https://github.com/intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/issues/63). By default, quasar is using `"@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^3.3.1"`. Changing that to `"@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^7.0.0"` solved the issue.